# how to install PIL with JPEG support on a raspberry pi?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pip, raspberry-pi

I tried to install [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) on my raspberry pi and read JPEG files. However, it does not work out of the box.

When I run the following:

```
sudo pip install pil
```

I receive the following error, trying to open an Image:

```
""decoder jpeg not available""
```

While trying to install all needed JPEG libraries I ran into some errors e.g.:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg
E: Unable to locate package libjpeg
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to re-install PIL and also install the needed libraries as well as link them manually. This answer is based on [this blog post](http://jj.isgeek.net/2011/09/install-pil-with-jpeg-support-on-ubuntu-oneiric-64bits/) for a regular ubuntu PIL installation and this [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211627/how-to-add-support-for-the-jpeg-image-format), where it is explained how to compile the jpeg encoding:

```
### uninstall PIL
sudo pip uninstall pil

### download and compile the JPEG library
wget http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz    
tar xvfz jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz
cd jpeg-8c
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=$CONFIGURE_PREFIX
make
sudo make install

### link the libraries correctly - RASPBERRY PI ONLY
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libfreetype.so /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libz.so /usr/lib

### install rest of the libraries, as well as freetrype and zlib
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev

### re-install PIL
sudo pip install pil
```

hope that helps someone!

Comment: I tried but got support available for freetype2 and ZLIB(png/zip) not for jpeg and tkinter. Any idea what could possibly went wrong ?

Comment: Thanks! I had to install using [this command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21243133/1167783), since PIL has now been replaced with Pillow: `pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL`

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. I used `pip install pillow` instead of `pip install pil`.

Comment: In case it should help future readers, the only part I needed was `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev`