# pip install PIL doesn't install into virtualenv

Tags: python-imaging-library, pip

How do I install PIL?

```
>pip install PIL

Downloading/unpacking PIL
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PIL  
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external PIL to allow). 
Cleaning up... 
No distributions at all found for PIL 
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log 

>pip uninstall PIL
Can't uninstall 'PIL'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Comment: These along with the above mentioned command by @JCotton helped me get PIL Installed on my Ubuntu 14.4 x64 https://gist.github.com/shingonoide/8172291
http://codeinthehole.com/writing/how-to-install-pil-on-64-bit-ubuntu-1204/

Answer (score 143, accepted):

`pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL`

This is due to changes in the new version of Pip. Run `pip --version` and I'm willing to bet you are running **1.5**. See the changelog [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/c2361e72da2c31a3596d49dc5fccb7d2bdb8c032/CHANGES.txt#L12-L15). This new default behavior enhances security. In PIL's case, the file you are installing actually comes from *effbot.org* (thus `--allow-external`) and PyPi doesn't have a checksum to guarantee validity (thus `--allow-unverified`).

Also, you might consider using the [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/) replacement to PIL.

Comment: thanks bro, it working, I've been using pillow, but But when I uploaded the picture it still did not show

Comment: I have another problem, pip uninstall PIL can't uninstall PIL  No files were found to uninstall.
how to uninstall PIL?

Comment: `pip uninstall PIL` works fine for me. Are you in the same virtualenv? Does `pip freeze` list PIL as being installed?

Comment: Well, looks like in Python 3.5.2 `--allow-external` and `--allow-unverified` got deprecated and has no longer any effect... Thought, `pip install pillow` seem to works fine.

Answer (score 38):

Updated info for those reading in 2016:

```
--allow-external
```

and

```
--allow-unverified
```

were recently deprecated. Installing packages external to PyPi using pip is no longer supported: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0470/

As an alternative, when you really need to install that external package, you can download the source code and run its setup.py. For example, for PIL 1.1.7, download from http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/, then:

```
$ tar xvfz Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz
$ cd Imaging-1.1.7
$ python setup.py install
```

(^ from the PIL README)

If you only want to install the package to a specific virtualenv, you can just activate your virtualenv first. ** thanks @Caumons

Alternatively, substitute the path to your virtualenv for 'python' in the third line, e.g.:

```
$ /home/username/virtualenv-name/bin/python setup.py install
```

Comment: great, just had to add a ´sudo´ in: ´$ python setup.py install´

Comment: @user2394901 if you use a virtualenv you shouldn't need to use `sudo` to install packages inside it!

Comment: Also if you are on debian jessie JPEG_ROOT probably needs to look something like this. `JPEG_ROOT = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/','/usr/include'`

Comment: @tated how could I install this trough an Unix terminal for a remote machine that I am running though Putty?

Comment: Is there an automatic way to do that?