# Django Pillow/PIL error

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to do the Tango with Django tutorial, which uses django 1.5. I'm using virtualenvwrapper. I installed Pillow with pip.

```
$ pip freeze
Django==1.5.5 
Pillow==2.4.0 
South==0.8.4 
wsgiref==0.1.2. 

(tangowithdjango)~/dev_django_projects/tangowithdjango$ which python
 /Users/7stud/.virtualenvs/tangowithdjango/bin/python
(tangowithdjango)~/dev_django_projects/tangowithdjango$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

However, in chapter 8 I get the following error:

```
(tangowithdjango)~/dev_django_projects/tangowithdjango$ ./manage.py syncdb
```

> CommandError: One or more models did not validate: rango.userprofile:
>   "picture": To use ImageFields, you need to install the Python Imaging
>   Library...

I am unable to install PIL, which is why I installed Pillow:

```
(tangowithdjango)~/dev_django_projects/tangowithdjango$ pip install PIL
Downloading/unpacking PIL
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PIL
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external PIL to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for PIL
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/7stud/.pip/pip.log
```

When I try:

```
$ pip install Pillow-PIL
```

which is supposed to convert buggy import statements into good import statements, I get the error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pillow-PIL
>   (from versions: 0.1dev)

Finally, if I try to use PIL in the shell:

```
(tangowithdjango)~/dev_django_projects/tangowithdjango$ ./manage.py shell
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from PIL import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/7stud/.virtualenvs/tangowithdjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 53, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/7stud/.virtualenvs/tangowithdjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /Users/7stud/.virtualenvs/tangowithdjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/7stud/.virtualenvs/tangowithdjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
>>>
```

Comment: if you want to try to install PIL you have to add the extra flags to pip.

`pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL`

Comment: possible duplicate of [pip install PIL dont install into virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242107/pip-install-pil-dont-install-into-virtualenv)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242107/pip-install-pil-dont-install-into-virtualenv)

```
pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
```