# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bg8.png'

Tags: python

I am new to Python & I'm doing a project in which I have to print so many pictures.But when I run the program I'm getting the following error,

```
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bg8.png'
```

I'm sure that the filename is correct and I have all the pictures including  'bg8.png'in my python folder.

Comment: The image should be in the same directory as your __script__

Comment: Is the scripts current working directory the same where the image is located?

Comment: Are any other pictures found? What does os.getcwd() report when you access the file path?

Answer (score 0):

You might have no permission to that file. Please check path and permission of `bg8.png`

Answer (score 0):

You need PIL library to allow/show png/jpeg based pictures. try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176883/how-to-install-pil-with-jpeg-support-on-a-raspberry-pi)

also try `os.chdir(directory)` and `pic = open("name.png)