# PIL decoder JPEG not available Raspberry

Tags: python, image, jpeg, python-imaging-library

i'm trying to utilize PIL to open a jpeg image and assign it to a Tkinter's label.
However whenever i try to open the image i get the same problem as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915296/python-image-library-fails-with-message-decoder-jpeg-not-available-pil)
I tried all the suggestions he got and also the ones i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176883/how-to-install-pil-with-jpeg-support-on-a-raspberry-pi) but it doesn't seem to fix, by installing PIL or Pillow(i tried that too) during the setup i get :

```
*** TKINTER support not available
*** JPEG support not available
```

And whenever i run my code i get an `IOError: decoder jpeg not available`
I'm using python 2.7.
Can someone provide a good method to make PIL or Pillow work with jpeg support? I've been googling extensively for two days, but all the possible fixes that i found don't seem to work for me

Comment: What is the result of the shell command `find /usr/lib -name libjpeg.so` on your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @halex i get:
 `/user/lib/libjpeg.so `

`/user/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so`

`/user/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/arm/libjpeg.so`

Answer (score 0):

Installing `libjpeg-dev` should do the trick, as proposed by the link you provided. But if it doesn't help (I ran into that as well) you can consider upgrading to [Pillow 3](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow), it looks like you are running Pillow 2. This also helped me getting rid of the errors, don't know why exactly..